# Setting a static ip in Ubuntu 14 is becoming an all day project today

Tags: networking, static-ip, ubuntu-14.04

I've never in my life have had so much difficulty in setting up a static ip. I've researched pass questions on askubuntu.com and have looked up multiple references and documents on setting up a static ip. I've ping several ip addresses like my gateway and i'm receiving packets but i ping google.com and don't get any. I've even pinged myself "the static ip i gave myself" and it returns packets. So right now i'm completely lost.

Here is what is in my interfaces file:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 10.25.12.201
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.25.12.10
```

I issued the following commmands and their results are as follows

```
ifconfig
-->eth0    Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:24:81:19:b2:ee
           inet addr:10.25.12.201 Bcast:10.25.12.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
           inet6 addr: fe80::224:81ff:fe19:b2ee/64 Scope:Link
           UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
           RX packets:1396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:63 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
           RX bytes:98518 (98.5 KB) TX bytes:8988 (8.9KB)
           Interrupt:19 Memory:f0500000-f0520000

   lo      Link encap:Local Loopback
           inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
           inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
           UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
           RX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
           TX packets:236 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
           collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
           RX bytes:17383 (17.3 KB) TX bytes:17383 (17.3 KB)


ping google.com
-->ping: unknown host google.com


ping 10.25.12.10
-->PING 10.25.12.10 (10.25.12.10) 56(84) bytes of data
-->64 bytes from 10.25.12.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.08 ms
-->64 bytes from 10.25.12.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.571 ms
-->10.25.12.10 ping statistics 
-->2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
-->rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.571/0.830/1.089/0.259 ms


ping 10.25.12.201
-->PING 10.25.12.201 (10.25.12.201) 56(84) bytes of data
-->64 bytes from 10.25.12.201: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.021 ms
-->1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
-->rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.021/0.021/0.021/0.000 ms
```

Any idea on how I can fix this. I've also done a networking restart and have restarted the computer several times. I've also included "auto lo" and "iface lo inet loopback" at the top of the file interfaces but it still doesn't work. Seems like no matter what I do I can't ping google.com and establish any kind of internet connection.

Comment: Is your DNS working?  Can you ping your DNS server?  Can you ping `8.8.8.8` (Google DNS server)?  Can you ping your gateway (`10.25.12.10`)?

Comment: @heavyd geez... i feel stupid. i forgot to specify my dns in the .conf file. However, if I restart my computer I have to respecify the dns in the .conf file. Anyway I can make it permanent or does this get complicated?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html#name-resolution

Comment: In 13.10 I was able to set a fixed IP through the network indicator, and the changes were permanent. I haven't upgraded to 14 yet, so I don't know if this still exists, but if it does then I recommend it as the simplest way to do what you want.

Comment: @heavyd thanks for your help. That link solved everything. this has been a wasteful afternoon and a learning one at the same time. cheers